# Проверка input на введенное число

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть `input`с типом `number`

```
<input type="number">

<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
```

Как мне сделать проверку на введенное содержимое? Я хочу, чтобы если пользователь ввел число `5`, то только тогда срабатывала кнопка `Отправить`.

Оценю любую вашу помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function submitForm() {
  var value = +document.getElementById("data").value;
  return value == 5;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitForm()">
  <input type="number" id="data">
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', e => {
   if (document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value !== '5') {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
 }
```