# Как проверить несколько input на введенные значения

Tags: javascript, html

В общем, у меня есть `input'ы` в количестве `9-ти` штук. В каждом из них при отправке должно быть конкретное число (здесь что-то в роде мини-игры, где только один ответ), объясните пожалуйста, как мне проверить содержимое `каждого из них`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так-так-так, подождите. Для одного инпута Вам сделали - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1077165  . Вы уже попробовали сделать для двух?

Comment: Заполняешь лист 9 инпутами. Затем по индексам проводишь вычисление и проверку.

Comment: Просто не совсем понятен принцип, то есть, я конечно могу сделать условие для каждого input, но, может быть есть более правильный способ написать код? Иначе получается дикий копипаст

Comment: Хорошо, я сейчас покажу нужный Вам принцип.

Comment: заранее спасибо вам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function submitForm(form) {
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input.data");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].value != inputs[i].dataset.value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitForm(this)">
  <input type="number" class="data" data-value="5">
  <input type="number" class="data" data-value="123">
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```