# Как проверить значение value с переданным значением

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть данный кусок кода. У меня есть 9 input'ов, мне нужно, чтобы при submit'e происходила проверка, если value = переданному значению datavalue, то тогда в консоль выводится текст.

```
handleChange(event) {
        const { target: { name, value } } = event;
        this.setState({
          [name]: value,
        })
      }

      handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const {
          datavalue,
        } = this.props;

        const {
          number,
        } = this.state;

        if (number.value === datavalue) {
          console.log('все верно!');
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }
```

Вот такая форма

```
<form className="home-page__form" onChange={onChange} onSubmit={onSubmit}>

        <InputCase datavalue="5" name="number" id="number" />
        <TextCase caption=":" />
        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="*" />
        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="= 14" />

        <TextCase caption="*" />
        <TextCase />
        <TextCase caption="-" />
        <TextCase />
        <TextCase caption="+" />
        <TextCase />

        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="+" />
        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="-" />
        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="= 5" />

        <TextCase caption="+" />
        <TextCase />
        <TextCase caption="+" />
        <TextCase />
        <TextCase caption="*" />
        <TextCase />

        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="-" />
        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="+" />
        <InputCase />
        <TextCase caption="= 6" />

        <TextCase caption="= 15" />
        <TextCase />
        <TextCase caption="= 0" />
        <TextCase />
        <TextCase caption="= 15" />
        <TextCase />

        <button type="submit">
          Отправить
        </button>
      </form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оценю любую вашу помощь, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема моего кода?

Comment: При нажатии кнопки "отправить" нужно проверить правильные ли значения находятся в каждой клетке?

Comment: да, в каждой клетке у меня должно быть конкретное значение (это что-то вроде мини-игры, здесь только один ответ). В каждой клетке какое-то конкретное число, нужно проверить каждую

Comment: @quires Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1077174/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-input-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-noether-0mw8o  Вместо этой строки: `JSON.stringify(data) == JSON.stringify(values)` можешь сравнивать объекты как угодно

Comment: благодарю, сейчас попробую сделать у себя по вашему методу.

Comment: все сделал. спасибо за помощь, код немного ругался, что нули переданы не как строка, пофиксил быстро)